Magento 2 : Error of continues reloading while apply and cancel of coupon code in checkout page
When trying to apply and cancel coupon code on the checkout page it continues reloading and getting an error in the console of cannot read the properties of undefined.
See the attached images below of the error:-



Try to disable third party extension those are use related any functionality for checkout.

Hey,
What is a full path of discount.min.js file ? can you try once disabled all third party modules and check.

I am facing the same issue. Did you get any solution?
Below is file path
https://commerce.adobedtm.com/v6/discount.min.js
